# How to pass pass values to constructor when instantiate kotlin class

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js

Assuming I have a class like this

```
class Foo(private val someVal: String) : RComponent<SomeProp, SomeState>(){
 ...
}
```

which I instantiate like so

```
child(
    Foo::class
) {
    attrs.bar = props.bar
    attrs.bar2 = props.bar2
    ...
}
```

How would I pass a value for `someVal` when instantiating the class? Note, this is KotlinJS with the React Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, because I haven't worked with Kotlin/React in a while, but I think you can't. When using `child(Foo::class)`, you're not responsible anymore for creating the instance, so you have to rely on the props object (`SomeProps` here) and set the props values. This is actually how react works: parameters for a component should be passed via props.

Also you might want to consider the new DSL for Kotlin React: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#pre282